# How to successfully access a webservice from the outside of the server?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I've been used to implement asp webservices in my projects within my company since I have access to  a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Now I would like to possess/rent my own IIS server, hosting my own webservice and be able to add a reference to this webservice in my project, in order for example to query different databases, hosted at different places, from different applications (WP applications or desktop application).

Problem is:

- My internet provider doesn't allow me to own a static IP, so I can't use my own computer as IIS server (though if there's a free solution for beeing able to acces my server from the outside through a dynamic IP, I would be interrested)
- I tried a free offer from a 3rd party IIS hosting server, but it appears I can only access my webservice from INSIDE the website included, but not from my WP application (even though I edited my web.config to redirect my webservice to an url, Visual Studio never detects it).

I don't really know if third party hosting companies provides this functionnality, I was wondering if the solution is to rent a dedicated server, but still, it is never specified if the webservices would be accessible from the outside.

What would be the best alternative that would fit my needs ? Or even are there well known companies that you'd know they'd provide this feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into something like http://www.noip.com/ to solve your problem of being forced to use a dynamic IP.

Comment: Sorry for the off topic. For the record, no-ip didn't work with my router so I used the cloud Azure service and hosted my web service there.